# How can I match the Query string with json data?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to match the query string with the JSON data, here is my query string:

https://www.localhost.com/contact/request-an-appointment/?id=27044

So I want the "id" to match with the JSON data, id is present in Html: field,
This is my JSON data looks like.

```
Results": [
      {
         "Geospatial": {
            "PoiTypeId": null,
            "PoiIcon": null,
            "PoiVariantId": null,
            "Latitude": 40.243,
            "Longitude": -76.9947,
            "Distance": 0.672,
            "Unit": "Miles"
         },
         "Id": "a98df0b8-fdd8-4573-a4cf-ffc0cb37ea5e",
         "Language": "en"
         "Name": null,
            "Html": "<div class=\"form-location-id field-id\">27044</div>
<div><button class=\"form-location-select\" onclick=\"GetFormLocation('', '27044', 'Select PT')\">Select</button ></div>
<div class=\"form-location-title field-nickname\">test nickname </div>
<div class=\"form-location-address field-address\">6108 test address  </div>
<div class=\"form-location-city field-city\">Test city  </div>
<div class=\"form-location-state field-state\">PA</div>
<div class=\"form-location-zip field-zip\">12345</div>"
```

Comment: so you want to fetch id from HTML ?, or as i can see there is one id field in your array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to fetch id from your Html, you can do something like below.

```
var data = {
         "Geospatial": {
            "PoiTypeId": null,
            "PoiIcon": null,
            "PoiVariantId": null,
            "Latitude": 40.243,
            "Longitude": -76.9947,
            "Distance": 0.672,
            "Unit": "Miles"
         },
         "Id": "a98df0b8-fdd8-4573-a4cf-ffc0cb37ea5e",
         "Language": "en",
         "Name": null,
            "Html": "<div class=\"form-location-id field-id\">27044</div>\
<div><button class=\"form-location-select\" onclick=\"GetFormLocation('', '27044', 'Select PT')\">Select</button ></div>\
<div class=\"form-location-title field-nickname\">test nickname </div>\
<div class=\"form-location-address field-address\">6108 test address  </div>\
<div class=\"form-location-city field-city\">Test city  </div>\
<div class=\"form-location-state field-state\">PA</div>\
<div class=\"form-location-zip field-zip\">12345</div>"}

for (i = 0; i < $(data.Html).length; i++) {

 var  element = $($(data.Html)[i]);
 if($(element).attr('class') == "form-location-id field-id")
 { 
   alert($(element).html())
 }

}
```

**you can check working demo on below [link]**

https://jsfiddle.net/xbdkvsq9/

Answer (score 0):

Very first you get the data from URL based the query string name

Like you mention your local URL in example

https://www.localhost.com/contact/request-an-appointment/?id=27044

You need to get by **ID** return value **27044**

https://www.localhost.com/contact/request-an-appointment/?id=27044&name="Test"

You need to get by **name** return value Test.

> Javascript code gets values from the URL using a query string parameter.

```
<script>  
    $(document).ready(function () {         
        var id = GetValuesFromUrl('id');  
        console.log(id);
        function GetValuesFromUrl(name) 
        {  
            try
            {
                var ourl = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');  
                for (var i = 0; i < ourl.length; i++) 
                {  
                    var parameters = ourl[i].split('=');  
                    if (parameters[0] == name) {  
                        return parameters[1];  
                    }  
                }               
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                    console.log("Error =>"+ e.message);
            }           
        }  
    });     
</script>
```

**Note: once you are done with getting data from URL then using filter function select data into JSON object.**

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you have the html from somewhere, then you can create a DOM Element, like this:

```
//Creating a div as a wrapper
var node = document.createElement("div");
//Putting the HTML into it as innerHTML
node.innerHTML = `<div class="form-location-id field-id">27044</div>
<div><button class="form-location-select" onclick="GetFormLocation('', '27044', 'Select PT')">Select</button ></div>
<div class="form-location-title field-nickname">test nickname </div>
<div class="form-location-address field-address">6108 test address  </div>
<div class="form-location-city field-city">Test city  </div>
<div class="form-location-state field-state">PA</div>
<div class="form-location-zip field-zip">12345</div>`;
//Getting the id
var id = node.querySelectorAll("div")[0].innerText
//redirecting to the correct id
window.location.href = window.location.href.substring(0, window.location.href.indexOf("=") + 1) + id;
```